# How can I change QSpinBox mouse click place. I want QSpinBox outside place and QMenu be same

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit, qmenu, qspinbox

[image]

When I change value and then I want to change color I can't, because when I change value and then click outside `QSpinBox` generating `SIGNAL(editingFilnished())` and then working `SLOT` hides `QMenu`. How can I change `QSpinBox` mouse click place. I want `QSpinBox` outside place and `QMenu` be same.

I want to generate this `SIGNAL(editingFilnished())` because I want do render one time.

Comment: Why does the connected slot hide your menu ? Also, you could try using `valueChanged()` instead of `editingFinished()`

Comment: I use editingFinished() becous I want take valu one time,,if I take it always when it had changed, I have to render every time.